# CSS GRID - How to make the rows extend to the container height?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning CSS and there is one thing that I have trouble understanding with CSS GRiD.

Imagine that I want to do the entire layout of the site with CSS GRID. How do I tell the container-grid to use the entire height of the page? (as it does for width).

For the columns part, we use for example "1fr" on at least one column.
But for the row part? If I put 1fr, the items does not extend to the bottom of the page.

The idea would be that when I extend my windows (verticaly and horizontaly), everything "grow" according to the container height and witdh. So whatever the size of the screen, the layout remains the same and only the size of container and elements changes (div, font, image ...).

I think there is something I don't understand but I can't find the solution.

Thank you :)

```
<body>    
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item item1">1</div>
        <div class="item item2">2</div>
        <div class="item item3">3</div>
        <div class="item item4">4</div>
        <div class="item item5">5</div>
        <div class="item item6">6</div>
        <div class="item item7">7</div>
        <div class="item item8">8</div>
        <div class="item item9">9</div>
        <div class="item item10">10</div>
        <div class="item item11">11</div>
        <div class="item item12">12</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
html{
    font-size: 62.5%; 
    background: rgb(21,56,125);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(21,56,125,1) 0%, rgba(91,47,87,1) 48%, rgba(133,16,16,1) 100%);
}


.grid-container{    
    display:grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( 2, minmax(100px, 500px) );
    grid-template-rows:  repeat( 12, 1fr );
    border-style: black solid 20px;
}

.item{
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E8DE42;
}

.item3{
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.item12{
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you need to tell the BODY tag to use height: 100% and width: 100%.  After that I made a few tweaks to your CSS GRID values:

https://codepen.io/lokase/pen/MWKKXWv

```
html, body {
    font-size: 62.5%; 
    background: rgb(21,56,125);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(21,56,125,1) 0%, rgba(91,47,87,1) 48%, rgba(133,16,16,1) 100%);

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.grid-container{    
    display:grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( 2 );
    grid-template-rows:  auto;
    border-style: black solid 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
}

.item{
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E8DE42;
}

.item3{
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.item12{
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: Great ! I tried the width and height but not on the body!
Thank you for your help :)